# Как поменять картинку с анимацией?

Tags: jquery

Всем привет.

Есть вот такой код.

Разметка:

```
 <div class="zoom">
<img src="путь"/>
</div>
```

Хотелось бы, чтобы при навидении на бок div менялась картинка внутри него. Вот что уже было написано!

```
$(function(){

    $('.zoom').hover(function(){

            $(this).animate({
                'margin-top':'0px',
                   }, 400);

        },

        function(){
                $(this).animate({
                'margin-top':'40px',
                }, 400);
        });

});
```

Сделано, для того чтобы при навидении блок отступал сверху и потом обратно!
Теперь как получить доступ к картинки в this и поменять атрибут src?

К сожалению, не очень силен в Jquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Вот пример](http://jsfiddle.net/c5672Lm2/) того, как это делается.

Добавляете в вашу функцию замену атрибута изображения, при наведении и при окончании наведения делаете снова исходную картинку.

```
$('.zoom').hover(function() {
            $(this).animate({
                'margin-top':'0px',
                   }, 400);
            $(this).find('img').attr('src','путь2');

        },
  function(){
      $(this).animate({
          'margin-top':'40px',
      }, 400);
      $(this).find('img').attr('src','путь1');
});
```

А вообще анимация, сделанная по hover, выглядит довольно-таки странно, сейчас изменение изображение и сдвиг при наведении можно сделать и на css, [вот пример](http://jsfiddle.net/c5672Lm2/2/), и работает даже лучше через через jQuery. Почитайте про `css transition` и `css transform`,  там есть много интересных эффектов.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь. По поводу Css круто выглядит, но только я всегда пугаюсь этим заниматься, т.к. IE работает криво, а нас в стране все сидят через IE!

Comment: @duddeniska, заинтриговали. Если не секрет, то что это за страна, где "*все сидят через IE*"?

Comment: Страна под названием Казахстан!

Comment: @duddeniska, http://yvision.kz/post/300270 а вот тут в статье пишут, что Казахстан раньше мировой общественности отказался от IE :) данные css-свойства поддерживаются IE10+, если IE версией ниже, то просто не будет работать плавно анимация, но всё будет работать и не ломаться

Comment: к сожалению, никак нет. У нас большинство ИП, и все сдают отчетность через Кабинет. Так вот этот кабинет нормально работает только в IE!!!